# Can't find html on Magento

Tags: magento

i have this on my Magento Store www.casekit.com.br and i need to change this html but i cant find

```
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
```

on catalg.xml i have this one

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
<action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
<action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key>
<key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
<action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
<action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
</block>
```

i need to edit this HTML file but i can't find, i always have this kind of problem with magento.

i tried to search another ways but i cant find anything

Thanks

Comment: you can try to find it in app/design/frontend/*package*/*theme*/template/catalog/product/info/container2.phtml , but not necessarily at all this file will be there. Just worth checking. Otherwise, enable Template hints in the right scope.

Answer (score 11):

1. **Log in** to the admin area
2. Go to **System->Configuration**, then to **Advanced->Developer** at the bottom-left
3. Top-left of your screen is a **Configuration Scope** dropdown. Click it, and select your **store view**
4. Expand "**Debug**" options. Set **Template Path Hints** to "**Yes**"
5. Click "**Save Config**" in top-right
6. Visit the **frontend** of your website and navigate to the page with the HTML you want to edit
7. A **red box** is around the HTML now. In **top-left**, it shows you path to the **template** where the HTML is derived
8. Find the **HTML template** in your **filesystem**.

   These are found in:

   `[magento]/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/*`
9. Make your edits

Comment: I followed your steps and cleared and deactivated the cache and deleted it in the browser, I even changed the browser, but no change at all.

Answer (score 2):

Enable template path hints. System -> Configuration -> Advanced tab -> Developer. If you change the configuration scope from default view to your store view 'Main Website'  ( the dropdown in the top left) a dropdown for template path hints appears in the Debug tab. Turn it on and reload the frontend, it will show you which template you need to edit.